# Kotlin/Micronaut - Add timeout for .map

Tags: kotlin

I am currently trying to work with Kafka and Micronaut, and I have a question on how to implement a timeout when processing a batch from Kafka, I know that Kafka has a timeout and retry configuration, but on this specific batch, I want to implement a custom timeout for its processing.

```
batchToProcess.map { item ->
    processItem(item)
}
```

Now I want to implement a timeout and when it throws the timeoutException after x milliseconds and send the batch to a retry topic.

Does anyone have any idea on what's the best approach for this situation?

Comment: "I know that Kafka has a timeout and retry configuration, but on this specific batch, I want to implement a custom timeout for its processing". Why? Just curious, since this usually points to an XY problem.

Comment: Hey Alex! Sorry for the late reply, but after thinking about what you said, I've left this idea behind to be able to think again in the future about how to improve this process.

But my problem was when I had a big batch processing, I am talking about 70000 items inside a batch, to prevent Kafka timeout, I was trying to add a timeout for this map function where its timeout was lesser than Kafka timeout, and when my map function throws the timeout, send again to the Kafka topic.

Comment: another solution would be to increase the Kafka timeout itself, if a process is long, then the process is long, not much else you can do about it.

Comment: Yeah, sadly I think its the best approach :/ 

Thank you for your help :D